# Async function in componentDidMount followed by a another component's render function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm using React-Redux.

I have a function that fetches collection data in my App's componentDidMount.

Then I have a Collection component that needs this data to render properly.

I can't use promises because they're both in different components.

What can I do?

Putting both functions in the same Component would be really bad for organizational purposes.

Comment: Hw does your code structure look like, and also what exactly is the problem here

Comment: Please post some example code.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you decide to use redux you have to store the data from the first component via action. Then connect the second one to redux and fetch the data from the state. The only requirement to make this working is to develop the second component like that so it works without data. When the data comes you trigger your logic. Or maybe you have to conditionally render the second component like

```
data && <SecondComponent data={ data } />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to dispatch a Async Action [Redux Async action](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) on the componentDidMount, this will update the state tree, after the satate tree is update the store look for all the listeners and all react component that are subscribe will update

You can use this middleware [React thunk middle ware](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or [Redux Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) for storing your `application state`. And `connect` all the component which need access to data.

You can use something [redux-saga](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or [redux thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) `for dispatching action which will call api to fetch data`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redux:
suppose if you make a fetch call in the first component, then in case of redux, it will automatically update the store through action creater which will dispatch an action that will call  the reducer with the new state, and it will update the store with new state .Now as soon as the other component will render, it will get the updated state in its component through its store.

Make this function in actions

```
const fetchContent = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return http.get(dispatch, `${config.serverUrl}/content`, null, {
     'Accept': CONTENT_LIST
    }).then((contentList) => {
      dispatch(contentsFetched(contentList))
    }).catch(handleErrors(dispatch))
  }
}

const contentsFetched = (contents) => ({
  type: constants.CONTENTS_FETCHED,
  contents
})
```

Reducer

```
case constants.CONTENTS_FETCHED:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        contents: action.contents,
        status: 'SUCCESS'
      })
```